# Mirror Git Repository Periodically

Tags: git, github

Let's say that I have two Git repositories that have been created. One repository is accessible to my software team internally but external customer access is not permitted (call this the *repository-to-mirror*). The other repository is accessible by my software team and my customer's software team (call this the *mirrored-repository*).

I'd like to push the changes three times per day (early morning, after lunch, end of day) to the *mirrored-repository*. What is the most recommend method to synchronize the changes in the *repository-to-mirror* with the *mirrored-repository* using Git?

I have done some research and found help pages on [mirroring a repository in another location](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/#mirroring-a-repository-in-another-location). It looks like the only option really is to define a different remote destination (the mirror) and push references to that repository. Is this correct?

Comment: Note that it's *possible* to have multiple URLs for a single remote. Not sure how usable that is in practice though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, this is usually the best way to accomplish mirroring.

If both teams will be committing to their respective repos, you might be better off with a more traditional fork rather than a mirror. Bi-directional mirroring is *theoretically* possible, but fraught with problems.

I wouldn't presume to tell you not to use this workflow, I'm very much a pragmatist when it comes to finding a workflow that meets your needs. But I will caution that 'git mirroring' is one of those phrases that throws up little red flags in my brain because it is often a solution to a symptom of a much bigger problem. So I will recommend taking a moment to step back and articulate your reasons.

For example, you might ask yourself: If everyone has access to the external repository, why not have everyone just use the external source? If the automatic answer is "security," bear in mind that you're *already* planning to push your codebase and history out to the remote. Of course, sometimes the answer is "the [laywers|owners|lizards] say so" at which point you just have to deal with it.